# How to capture click event when in hovered state in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a horizontal carousel which has a structure like below

```
ul
  <li>
    <a>
     <img>

  <li>
    <a>
     <img>

  <li>
    <a>
     <img>
```

Jquery code for hover animation is below

```
$('ul li a img').hover(function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({ height: '60px', width: '60px'}, 200);
}, function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({ height: '44px', width: '44px'}, 200);
});`
```

Hover is working fine but now I need to capture click event on hovered img. For this I have code below

```
$('ul li a img').click(function() {
    console.log($(this));
    return true;
});
```

The click event is triggered equal to number of items in carousel. If there are 20 items, click event is trigger 20 times but I only want it to trigger 1 time for hovered item.

Thanks

Comment: just remove the return true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're returning `true` from the click handler, which causes the event to bubble up (not entirely sure why, unless perhaps you have the images stacked on top each other). Returning `false` should make the event stop propagating after the first click is handled.

```
$('ul li a img').click(function() {
    console.log($(this));
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Then you're assigning a click handler inside a loop perhaps? Otherwise, create a fiddle or jsbin and let us see what exactly you're doing. @user1352961

Comment: this solved my problem I was indeed assigning click handler inside a loop

Answer (score 0):

```
$('ul li a img').on('click',function(e){
 //your code
 e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo can also use [`e.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) function:

```
$('ul li a img').click(function(e) {
    console.log($(this));
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Then click event will not be propagated to another nodes.

Comment: this did not fix the issue.